# Replace <input type="submit" with HTML in SimpleSearchForm's tpl Chunk?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I want to replace the `<input>` element in SimpleSearchForm's tpl Chunk with HTML, specifically a Font Awesome

```
<i class="fa fa-search" id="searchIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

But, no matter what I adjust it wont send.

Would anyone know what I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `input` element with `button`:

```
<button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" id="searchIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

after chage some css - you will get what you want.